# Table Views. View controller vs Table View controller?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xcode5, uitableview

I have been watching a lot of tutorials on Table Views, table view cells etc. When creating a table view why choose a UIViewController over a UITableViewController in Xcode? For instance what would be the main benefits of creating a UIViewController and then adding a tableView object, over just creating a UITableViewController? I have already created a large numbers of scenes within storyboard and I hope I haven't limited myself in doing so. I hope my question is clear as I am new to coding!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIViewController` gives you more control over `tableview` rather than `UITableViewController`. You should use `UITableViewController` only when you are just concerned with tableview in a controller. But if you want to add more subviews/controls in a controller other than `tableview`, then you have to use `UIViewController`.

**EXAMPLE:**

If you just want to display **grocery items list** with some header and footer, then tableviewcontroller should be priority. But if you want to display **mail items** in tableview, you would need some additional buttons for altering items in mail(tableview). For later case, you will use viewcontroller. Hope my point is clear.

Comment: Thank you both. I have created a storyboard with nearly 50 connected UITableViewControllers scenes with tableview basic static cells, all labelled. Is there a way to be able to change the scenes form a UITVC to a UIVC without effecting the labelled cells? Or will I have to create all the scenes again?

Answer (score 0):

I think the benefits of having a View Controller is just more versatility and you will have a easier time to add other views other than the UItableview. Whereas UITableViewController i just inheriting a UIViewController, but with the delegates already set up for you. Basically it is assuming you will have a UITableView for sure. In the end it shouldn't really limit you, just cause you used UITableViewController, since everything you want to do in UIViewController, you can do in UIViewController.